# (URI tag not populated) Metrics on Spring Boot 3.1.5 and WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient

I just made a migration of a project running on Spring Boot 2.7 to Spring Boot 3.1.

I don't have an issue with my metrics when using RestTemplate but with WebClient. I don't have my URI tag populated.

```
  @Bean
  public MyClient myClient(
      ClientProperties clientProperties,
      WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
    return new MyClient(webClientBuilder, clientProperties);
  }
```

I'm defining a client and I'm putting a WebClient.Builder in the method arguments so that Spring uses the one it has auto configured ([Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.0/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.metrics.supported.http-clients)).

> Spring Boot Actuator manages the instrumentation of both RestTemplate
> and WebClient. For that, you have to inject the auto-configured
> builder and use it to create instances:
>
> - RestTemplateBuilder for RestTemplate
> - WebClient.Builder for WebClient

When I'm calling an API using WebClient. It does something as it saves a metric in my actuator endpoint but I don't have my uri tag populated anymore, I have a none value :

[image: Actuator http.client.requests metrics endpoint]

Any clue ? I tried defining my own ObservationWebClientCustomizer but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a workaround for my issue, I'm adding a new ClientRequestObservationConvention where I can update the URI tag value.

```
  @Bean
  public MyClient myClient(
      ClientProperties clientProperties, WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
    webClientBuilder.observationConvention(new CustomizedClientRequestObservationConvention());
    return new Client(webClientBuilder, clientProperties);
  }
```

My custom ClientRequestObservation :

```
public class CustomizedClientRequestObservationConvention
    extends DefaultClientRequestObservationConvention {


  public CustomizedClientRequestObservationConvention() {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  protected KeyValue uri(ClientRequestObservationContext context) {
    if (context.getCarrier() != null) {
      ClientRequest request = context.getCarrier().build();
      return KeyValue.of(LowCardinalityKeyNames.URI, request.url().getPath());
    }
    return KeyValue.of(LowCardinalityKeyNames.URI, KeyValue.NONE_VALUE);
  }
}
```

Strangely, in my case `context.getRequest()` was `null`. I'm using `context.getCarrier()` to have access to the request attributes.

I'm posting this in case someone has the same problem as me. And if someone have a better solution, that'll be great.